# VBA Selenium Select a value from drop down menu

Tags: vba, selenium, dropdown, findelement

and thank you for reading..
New to selenium ( 4 days only)
I want to select a value from the dropdown part highlighted in the image. I need to select the value "Late Speed" to the drop down selection,however I think this is a dynamic dropdown (?)

[image]

[image]

I have been playing around with the following code but not having much luck.

```
For Each tr2 In driver.FindElementsByClass("sectional-filters")

  For Each td2 In tr2.FindElementsByClass("sectional-filters__select")
  Debug.Print td2.Text

  If InStr(td2.Text, "Late Speed") > 0 Then
    tr2.FindElementsByTag("id").Click
    tr2.FindElementByClass("sectional-filters__select").Click
    
  End If
Next td2
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use selenium? Why not use queryselector?

Comment: Hi , was told that Selenium was the tool to use with VBA as the web site has a lot of JScript?

Comment: Try `td2.Click` instead of `tr2.FindElementsByTag("id").Click
    tr2.FindElementByClass("sectional-filters__select").Click`

Comment: didn't work :-(